# JavaScript - Get string from position till end of line / return character

Tags: javascript, substr

I have a string, it gets squished into one line with a (return?) character, but should be like this:

```
Service Type: Registration Coordinator

Authorized Amount: $4
Authorized Mileage: $1.25
```

I want to get 'Registration Coordinator' or whatever is there till the end of the line, so I tried this:

```
var service_type = t_var.description.substr(t_var.description.indexOf('Service Type: ') +14,t_var.description.indexOf('\n'));
```

But it returns:

```
Registration Coordinator

Authorized A
```

Here is how the original string was created before being posted to the DB, I'm trying to work with it after it has been read back from the DB:

```
var fullDescription = "Service Type: " + that.current_wo_data.service_partner.skill + "\n\n";
fullDescription += '\nAuthorized Amount: $' + that.$('#authorized_amount').val();
fullDescription += '\nAuthorized Mileage: $' + that.$('#authorized_mileage').val();
```

Thanks

Comment: `str.split('\n').shift().split(':').pop();`

Comment: @adeneo Don't you mean `\n`?

Comment: @rhino - oops, small typo, and it should probably be `.split(/[\n\r]/)` for certain older browsers as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between `substr` and `substring` (don't ask me why)

```
.substr(start_pos, number_of_chars);
"abcdef".substr(2, 3) returns "cde"
.substring(start_pos, end_pos);
"abcdef".substr(2, 3) returns "c"
```

You are using `start_pos` and `end_pos` with the function `substr`. That's asking for trouble ;)

```
var service_type = t_var.description.substr(t_var.description.indexOf('Service Type: ') +14,t_var.description.indexOf('\n'));
```

Should be

```
var service_type = t_var.description.substring(t_var.description.indexOf('Service Type: ') +14,t_var.description.indexOf('\n'));
```